# My son sleeps too much

Tags: sleep, pre-schooler

MY 4 yrs,11mths old boy sleeps too much but mostly at school. He has just changed schools, but there was no report of similar behaviour from his previous school.

It is getting worrisome as this is beginning to affect his school works. He is a very active and intelligent boy, but he sleeps so deeply that it takes effort to wake him up when he sleeps in school.

His bed time is between 7 and 8 pm.

Comment: When is the wake-up time? Does he have an age-appropriate amount of time available to sleep at night? If so, this is probably a question for his pediatrician.

Answer (score 4):

How well does he sleep? My boy had sleep apnea so, even though he got a lot of sleep, he was always tired and would often lie down on the floor. His was caused by excessively large tonsils and adenoids which would restrict his breathing.

An oximetry test was performed to check his oxygen levels throughout the night - his would fall below 80% - not a good sign. This was free where we live (Australia).

Our GP did not pick up on his breathing issues because we only take him to the GP when he's sick.

It could be worth getting your son checked out and specifically asking about breathing issues and sleep apnea.

Answer (score 0):

Young children typically sleep longer than adults e.g. 12 hours of sleep is normal. Determine whether he has enough sleep e.g. he wakes up by himself in the morning.

Check that your son is not awaken regularly awake by noise in your household or from outside. Also talk to your son about it.

As others mentioned, health problems can also affect his sleeping. You might need to consult pediatrician or family doctor.